# Repeat different elements of an array different amounts of times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, repeat

Say I have an array with longitudes, lonPorts

```
lonPort =np.loadtxt('LongPorts.txt',delimiter=',')
```

for example:

```
lonPort=[0,1,2,3,...]
```

And I want to repeat each element a different amount of times. How do I do this? This is what I tried:

```
Repeat =[5, 3, 2, 3,...]

lonPort1=[]

for i in range (0,len(lenDates)):
   lonPort1[sum(Repeat[0:i])]=np.tile(lonPort[i],Repeat[i])
```

So the result would be:

```
lonPort1=[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,...]
```

The error I get is:

```
list assignment index out of range
```

How do I get rid of the error and make my array?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.repeat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
np.repeat(a, [5,3,2,3])
```

Example:

```
In [3]: a = np.array([0,1,2,3])

In [4]: np.repeat(a, [5,3,2,3])
Out[4]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Assuming OP actually wants arrays as opposed to the lists in the question.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, this is implied from their use of `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Without relying on numpy, you can create a generator that will consume your items one by one, and repeat them the desired amount of time.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
repeat = [4, 3, 2, 1]

def repeat_items(x, repeat):
  for item, r in zip(x, repeat):
    while r > 0:
      yield item
      r -= 1


for value in repeat_items(x, repeat):
  print(value, end=' ')
```

displays `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3`.

Comment: I'd write that `while r > 0` as `for _ in range(r)` and get rid of the `r -= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a numpy-free solution for future readers that might want to use lists.

```
>>> lst = [0,1,2,3]
>>> repeat = [5, 3, 2, 3]
>>> [x for sub in ([x]*y for x,y in zip(lst, repeat)) for x in sub]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

If `lst` contains mutable objects, be aware of the [pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) of sequence multiplication for sequences holding mutable elements.